# PHP - Break after return?

Tags: php, for-loop, return, break

do I need to use break here or will it stop looping and just return once?

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
    if($var[$i] === '') return false;
    // break;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It will run just once, stop looping, and exit from the function/method.

It could be argued though that this is bad style. It is very easy to overlook that `return` later, which is bad for debugging and maintenance.

Using `break` might be cleaner:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
    if($var[$i] === '')
     { set_some_condition; 
       break;
     }
}

if (some_condition)
 return;
```

Answer (score 16):

**Update**:

PHP 7 requires a `return`. A `break;` is not needed because the loop ends on `return`.

A `break;` is usually used in a switch or loop whenever you have found your needed item.

**Example:**

```
$items = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']; 

foreach($items as $item) 
{ 
   if($item == 'a') 
   {
       return true; // the foreach will stop once 'a' is found and returns true. 
   }
   
   return false; // if 'a' is not found, the foreach will return false.
}
```

or:

```
$items = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']; 
    
foreach($items as $item)
{
    return $item == 'a'; // if 'a' is found, true is returned. Otherwise false.
}
```

Comment: `return` works . Simple example :

`$items = ['a' , 'b' , 'c'];

foreach($items as $item) {
    
    echo $item;

    if($item == 'a')
        
        return true;
    
}`

Comment: Thanks @EGurelli. I've added and edited your example.

Comment: The second snippet is misleading/bad -- it will never perform more than one iteration.  In other words there is no reason to use a `foreach()` in the second snippet -- it could merely be `return $items[0] == 'a';`.

Answer (score 13):

If you use `return`, your function (or entire script) will return - all code after that won't be executed. So to answer your question: a `break` is not required here. However, if the `break` was not commented out here, the loop would have stopped after one iteration. That's because your if statement doesn't use braces (`{ ... }`) so it only covers the `return` statement (in other words: the `break` in your example is always executed).